# HTML menu moves down when adding content

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to write a simple menu for my site's backend. I'd like to acomplish that there is no space between the menu an the top of my site. It looks ok until I add a `<h>` or `<p>`
 element. The menu moves about 30px down.
 Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<head >
<title>my page</title>
<link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
   <div id="PageWrapper">
        <nav>
            <ul id="navMenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Manage Books</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">New Book</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Reservations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lendings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Back>></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <section>

         <h1>Welcome to the management part of your site.</h1>

        <section>           

    </div>
```

And the css file:

```
body {

   margin: 0;
   background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#PageWrapper {

   width: 1000px;
   margin: auto;
}

nav {

   clear: both;
   width: 100%;
   float:left;
   margin-bottom:30px;
   margin-top:0px;
   background-color:#666666;
}

ul#navMenu {

    padding:0px;
    margin:auto;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#navMenu ul {

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

 ul#navMenu li {

    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

 ul#navMenu a {

    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #666666;
    color: #ffffff;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

    ul#navMenu a:hover {
        background: #cccccc;
        color: #333333;
    }

    ul#navMenu li:hover ul {

       display: block;
}

    ul#navMenu ul a {

       width: 150px;
}

    ul#navMenu ul li {

       display: block;
       margin: 0px;
}
```

I tried to look for unwanted margins in browser developer tools but I haven't seen anything obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float` and `clear` from `nav` and replace with `overflow:hidden` to contain the floats applied to the underlying `li` menu items.

This forces the `nav` into a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context), which will display as anticipated.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/5ajnuwe3/)

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    margin-top:0px;
    background-color:#666666;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Another problem here.I didn't noticed it for the first time. When I have rearranged the css as you said ,the submenu item is now hidden..any ideas how to fix that?